# Ruby on Rails not reading updated config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, config

I have a controller aborting at an action to print out a config file's variable. I was editing it yesterday no problem, but all of a sudden it stopped reading the updated file so no matter what I set the variable value to, it would read an older value (which I'd previously set).

My config file is dna.yml, the code to abort is: `abort(DNA[:client].to_s)`, `:client: 1020` will print out 1390 (which was it's previous value).

Can anyone help? I'm currently downloading an alternative FTP client thinking that may be the problem, I'm not sure.

Comment: did you restart your rails app?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have that ability as it's hosted on a client's server which is linked to live sites that cannot go down. Do you think this will effect it? I renamed a log file from staging.log to staging_.log and it managed to update staging_.log instead of a new staging.log file.

Comment: @StefanDunn You don't have to restart the entire machine, just restart your app's specific app server so that the app's initializers are reloaded. How to do it depends on how your app is deployed in production.